# Get maxAbs from array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Why i can't get the element from my array 'vec' which have the max abs value in absolute form? Where's the error?

```
return vec.Select(Math.Abs).Max();
```

Comment: That code works fine for me. What's in `vec`? What's the problem?

Comment: You need to be more explicit, the code you have as written looks like it should work. Are you getting a compiler error or are you getting a value you did not expect to get? You need to elaborate your question. Use http://dotnetfiddle.net/ to create a sample program that recreates the problem and post the entire code of that in to your question.

Comment: It could fail when `vec` doesn't contain any elements.

Comment: Vec is the name of my array and my array contains inserted values from user..

Comment: @JorgeAndré I tried `vec = inserted values from user` and it didn't compile. What inserted values from user? What data type? What are they? What are the values? Strings? Please provide enough code for us to reproduce the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2):

You, probably, mean **ArgMax**, not **Max**

> the **element** ... which have the max abs value

*Linq* doesn't provide such a method, but you can easily emulate it:

```
var result = vec.Aggregate((a, s) => Math.Abs(a) > Math.Abs(s) ? a : s);
```

Test:

```
int[] vec = new int[] { 1, -3, 2 };

var result = vec.Aggregate((a, s) => Math.Abs(a) > Math.Abs(s) ? a : s);

// The output is "-3" (the element in the array)
Console.Write(result);
```

**Edit:** if you're looking for the array's *index*, all you have to do is to modify the code a bit:

```
var result = vec
  .Select((value, index) => new {
      Value = value,
      Index = index })
  .Aggregate((a, s) => Math.Abs(a.Value) > Math.Abs(s.Value) ? a : s)
  .Index;

// Output: "vec[1] == -3"
Console.Write($"vec[{result}] == {vec[result]}");
```

Comment: if the array just receive type double, example : 3,1 | 2,1 | 1,1 will output be 3? ( following my example)

Comment: @Jorge André: the outcome of the `[3.1, 2.1, 1.1]` will be `3.1` (the element of the array)

Comment: yea my output is the same like that but i need 3 not 3.1 . thats my problem and i cant resolve

Comment: @Jorge André: what is `3` then? Are you looking for array's *index*?

Comment: No. 3,1 is an element from my array..

Comment: Hey Dmitry, i resolved with Math.floor. Thank you!